# Url convention: article/1234/article-name vs articles/1234/article-name

Tags: url, conventions

I asking just for your opinion, of what make more sense.

Currently, this is my design:

```
www.site.com/articles                     <-- list
www.site.com/article/1234/article-name    <-- details
www.site.com/article/write                <-- write new article
```

Is is make sense too you? or article'**s** make more sense?

Can you tell me what can be wrong with this approach?

Comment: Not a programming question. I think it belongs to doctype.com

Comment: SO seems to use "questions" universally, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807624/url-convention-article-1234-article-name-vs-articles-1234-article-name and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ .  So I guess we know Fog Creek's opinion on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

For me (not that it matters)...but I'd use either **article** or **articles**...but not both

```
www.site.com/article                      <-- list
www.site.com/article/1234/article-name    <-- details
www.site.com/article/write                <-- write new article

www.site.com/articles                     <-- list
www.site.com/articles/1234/article-name   <-- details
www.site.com/articles/write               <-- write new article
```

and of those two, the second looks better to me...

Answer (score 0):

The scheme is reasonable, but I wouldn't make any user try to remember raw URLs for hand entry.